# Console opens when running GUI C++ application

Tags: visual-c++, user-interface, visual-studio-2012

I'm currently making a C++ GUI application, but I have the following problem. In the program I have one MyForm.cpp and one Myform.h (just one button). When the application starts the console and the form opens. Is this default? Or how can I disable it? The code in the main is:

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
int main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Namespace::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Hope that someone can help?

Comment: I appears you are not actually compiling it as windows application. There is an option somewhere in the project settings to switch between console and windows application (windows application can't use console, at all, while console application can show forms, but always has console visible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in your .pro file :

```
ENTRY = mainCRTStartup
```

OR

in VS, right click on your project -> properties -> linker -> system

And select "Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)" for SubSystem.

Comment: This works but I had to added: /ENTRY:"mainCRTStartup" to Properties --> Linker --> Command Line

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a CRT build and there is no WinMain function you can use this:

`#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")//hide console window`

to hide the console.

Comment: I am not sure whether pragma hidden somewhere in code is the best place for compiler options.

Comment: It's a code question so I though I shall answer with code, else just go to linker options and change the subsystem to windows.. (But you are required to have "WinMain" if you do that)

Comment: Actually it's a nice, even if hackish, solution.